# Woocommerce - Override the default templates location under the theme directory

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

As per official woocommerce documentation ([here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)), the proper and safe way to override default woocomerce templates via theme is to create a sub-folder under the theme directory with the `'default'` name `/woocommerce` and copy the targeted templates into it and make some changes ..

Example: to override the `archive-product.php` template,
copy:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php
```

to

```
wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/woocommerce/archive-product.php
```

So is there any possible way to override the default woocommerce templates folder : `/woocommerce` under the theme directory and move it to an other folder let say `/<your-theme>/plugins/woocommerce` ?

in fact, many plugins out there (woocommerce, bbpress among others) suggest creating sub-folder under the theme directory with the name of the plugin (`/woocommerce`, `/bbpress`) to hold the overridden templates and in order to bring some organization to my theme folder it does make sens to me to create sub-folder `/plugins` under my theme directory where i can hold my own templates so `archive-product.php` would be located under

```
/<my-theme>/plugins/woocommerce/archive-product.php
```

and not

```
/<my-theme>/woocommerce/archive-product.php
```

as expected.

i looked at those core functions: `wc_get_template_part`, `wc_get_template`, `wc_get_template_html` and `wc_locate_template` under `/includes/wc-core-functions.php` but i can't figure out how to override the default location (applying filters ..)

i appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the `woocommerce_template_path` hook/filter:

```php
// $path defaults to 'woocommerce/' (in your theme folder)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_template_path', function( $path ){
    $my_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/woocommerce/';
    return file_exists( $my_path ) ? 'plugins/woocommerce/' : $path;
} );
```

It should work whether you're overriding only specific files or all — i.e. you copy all files and folders from `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` to your theme.

Comment: thx a lot for your quick hint, i'll give it try and come back to you. yes it should work.

Comment: Sure, take your time.

Comment: yes, it works as expected and i accept your answer, but the only thing i got is that my theme is getting rendered little bit slower (even before i add this filter, i mean with the default woocommerce's location '/woocommerce' under the theme directory), i have to say i'm trying to override the 'whole' woocommerce templates to support bootstratp 4 (lot of work) so do you have any idea who to optimize the loading time later on server ? i'm working on my local machine.

Comment: There are various performance optimization you could do - use valid HTML/CSS/JS/PHP, avoid using unnecessary JS/PHP code/scripts/libraries (i.e. use only what you need), use functions than repeating the same block of code, etc. - but are you sure it's the theme causing the issue? Have you tried a default theme? How about disabling all plugins except WooCommerce?